# ms access - return records from sql Stored procedure

Tags: ms-access, adodb, ms-access-2010

I have an access 2010 and I want to call a sql stored proc on a sql 2008 server and return the results to a recordset or bind directly to a report.

The method below returns the error "feture not available in ADP" or something like that - It works with a Form but not with a Report.

How do I go about doing this?

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cm As New ADODB.Command

'Use the ADO connection that Access uses
Set cn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0"
    .Properties("Data Provider").Value = "SQLOLEDB"
    .Properties("Data Source").Value = "dsidsw923"
    .Properties("Integrated Security").Value = "SSPI"
    .Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = "Promotions_Dev_DSI"
    .Open
End With

'Create an instance of the ADO Recordset class, and
'set its properties
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With cm
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = "spCheckProdWkConsist"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    Set rs = .Execute()
End With

'Set the form's Recordset property to the ADO recordset
Set Me.Recordset = rs

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
Set cm = Nothing
```

Comment: You may wish to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184871/adodb-recordset-as-access-report-recordsource

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a view to wrap the results of the stored procedure (`exec usp_whatever`) and then create a linked table to the new view.

Also, you may be able to create a passthrough query (`exec usp_whatever`) that executes your stored procedure and returns your results directly.  Then just bind your report or form to the query.

Comment: You can`t select * from a stored procedure. If you can provide code sample of passthrough query that would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: OK, then you can wrap the exec in a view, or use the passthrough query.